# C# visual studio error use of unassigned local variable

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am making a simple program that when a button is clicked it displays a card in the label

Using random number generator to create a number between 1-4 (and set to either hearts, diamonds, clubs or spades)

also another generator to create a number between 1-13 (and then set to either ace, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,jack,queen,king)

then using if statement to set the suit to which is called

then using switch statement to set the card to its respective card

but i am receiving an error:

Error CS0165 when trying to build my program

here is my program:

[program form1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAJzZ.png)

here is my code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random myRandom = new Random();
        int suitNo, cardNo;
        string suit, card;

        suitNo = myRandom.Next(1, 4);
        cardNo = myRandom.Next(1, 13);

        if (suitNo == 1)
        {
            suit = "Hearts";
        }
        if (suitNo == 2)
        {
            suit = "Diamonds";
        }
        if (suitNo == 3)
        {
            suit = "Clubs";
        }
        if (suitNo == 4)
        {
            suit = "Spades";
        }

        switch (cardNo)
        {
            case 1:
                card = "Ace";
                break;
            case 2:
                card = "Two";
                break;
            case 3:
                card = "Three";
                break;
            case 4:
                card = "Four";
                break;
            case 5:
                card = "Five";
                break;
            case 6:
                card = "Six";
                break;
            case 7:
                card = "Seven";
                break;
            case 8:
                card = "Eight";
                break;
            case 9:
                card = "Nine";
                break;
            case 10:
                card = "Ten";
                break;
            case 11:
                card = "Jack";
                break;
            case 12:
                card = "Queen";
                break;
            case 13:
                card = "King";
                break;
        }

        label1.Text = "Your card is a " + card + " of " + suit;
    }
```

any ideas as to why its giving me an error?

Comment: Why don't you use `switch` with `suitNo`? at the very least you should use `if else`.

Comment: Both suit and card can be left unassigned as far as the compiler is concerned.  You'll say "no way" since you always have 4 suits and 13 cards, but the compiler does not know how to play the game.  Simple workaround is to initialize the variable in its declaration.

Comment: You also have an error in your arguments for `Random.Next`. Due to this error, you will never get the King of Spades :-( (Check the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

Comment: @HansPassant I initialized the variables at declaration to string suit = "", card = "" and it now works (odd how it wasnt necessary for the int suitno and cardno??)good point about the complier not knowing the game, your suggested simple workaround worked perfectly thanks :)

Comment: @elgonzo infact i didnt get any King cards drawn as well as spades drawn at all, and changing the upper limit values of myRandom.Next to (1,5) and (1,14) fixed it... I'll have to remember that one, cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `switch` clause does not provide a `default` case and therefore the compiler can not statically deduce that a value will always be assigned to `card`. Even though in practice `cardNo` will be between `1` and `13`, this can not be verified without running the program.

The same goes for `suit` of course.

Either initialize the values of `suit` and `card` before the `switch` clause or create a `default` case.

a good practice for when you do not expect any other value than those you have coded for is to provide a `default` case in which you simply throw an exception or `Debug.Assert(false)`.

A simpler structure altogether would be to define

```
private static readonly string[] suits = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades" };
private static readonly string[] cards = { "Ace", ... , "King" };
```

And then your method could basically be reduced to:

```
int suitNo = myRandom.Next(suits.Length);
int cardNo = myRandom.Next(cards.Length);
string suit = suits[suitNo];
string card = cards[cardNo];
```

And absolve yourself from the verbose `if`s and `switch`es.

Comment: I don’t think `Debug.Assert` will work when you decide to compile in release mode as this call would be removed by the compiler if I remember correctly.

Comment: @ckuri Depending on the use case that may be desired behavior. Just giving both options.

Comment: No, not `suits.Length - 1` nor `cards.Length - 1`. The upper bound provided to Random.Next is _exclusive_.

Comment: @elgonzo My bad, I was following the syntax in the OP when I should have checked the docs. Fixed

Comment: @Rotem I thought it wasnt necessary to have a default switch case? perhaps using a default switch case is the reason? i will try declare the values of suit and card to "" at the top, maybe outside the button click method ? ill report back

Answer (score -1):

> Both suit and card can be left unassigned as far as the compiler is concerned. You'll say "no way" since you always have 4 suits and 13 cards, but the compiler does not know how to play the game. Simple workaround is to initialize the variable in its declaration. – Hans Passant 9 hours ago

initializing the variables string suit and card at the beginning fixed my error,

> You also have an error in your arguments for Random.Next. Due to this error, you will never get the King of Spades :-( (Check the documentation: learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/…) – elgonzo 9 hours ago

also changing the `myRandom.Next` from `1,4` and `1,13` to `1,5` and `1,14` meant i now get all cards displayed, as @elgonzo pointed out, `1,4` and `1,13` would mean no king of spades would be drawn, not only just the king of spades but king from all suits and the entire spade suit would not be drawn - until i changed the upper limit to `1,5` and `1,14`

see the working code below:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random myRandom = new Random();
        int suitNo, cardNo;
        string suit = "", card = "";

        suitNo = myRandom.Next(1, 5);
        cardNo = myRandom.Next(1, 14);

        if (suitNo == 1)
        {
            suit = "Hearts";
        }
        if (suitNo == 2)
        {
            suit = "Diamonds";
        }
        if (suitNo == 3)
        {
            suit = "Clubs";
        }
        if (suitNo == 4)
        {
            suit = "Spades";
        }

        switch (cardNo)
        {
            case 1:
                card = "Ace";
                break;
            case 2:
                card = "Two";
                break;
            case 3:
                card = "Three";
                break;
            case 4:
                card = "Four";
                break;
            case 5:
                card = "Five";
                break;
            case 6:
                card = "Six";
                break;
            case 7:
                card = "Seven";
                break;
            case 8:
                card = "Eight";
                break;
            case 9:
                card = "Nine";
                break;
            case 10:
                card = "Ten";
                break;
            case 11:
                card = "Jack";
                break;
            case 12:
                card = "Queen";
                break;
            case 13:
                card = "King";
                break;
        }

        label1.Text = "Your card is a " + card + " of " + suit;
```